# Setting the bottom bar as a tab bar programmatically in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In IB, I can set the bottom bar as a tab bar for a view as below screen shot, but how can I set it by code in the implement(.m) file?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create an `NSArray` of the `UIViewController`s that you want to use. Then instantiate a `UITabBarController` and set the `viewControllers` property to this array. Then add the `view` of the `tabBarController` to the window. All this should be done in the AppDelegate.m file. For example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{   

    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    CustomViewController *vc3 = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, nil];
    [vc1 release]; [vc2 release]; [vc3 release];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    [window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```